# Upgrading issue "Amount can only be increased by 20% " in paypal

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I have integrated the Paypal subscription option into my site.My problem is when i try to upgrade the subscription it shows an error in Paypal

Amount can only be increased by 20%

Subscription amount is $0.25 Upgrade amount is $0.59

How can i increase the percentage of the amount .

the code is following :

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="charset" value="utf-8">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="freelancecoachpro@gmail.com">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="FreelanceCoachPro Total Connect">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="7">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="0.59">
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M"> <!-- Set recurring payments until canceled. -->
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="1388035301:63:7:b09c926d4df9a5f17221e56cbe688297:6">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://www.freelancecoachpro.com/thank-you/">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="https://www.freelancecoachpro.com/subscriptions-5/">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.freelancecoachpro.com/paymentreturn/paypalexpress">
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="modify" value="2"><!-- Display the payment button. -->
<input type="image" name="submit" border="0" src="https://www.freelancecoachpro.com/images/upgrade_button.png" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
<img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the note for `AMT` on [this page](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_NVP/), it looks like this is a PayPal restriction (I would assume Payments Standard would have the same restriction)

> Note: For recurring payments with Express Checkout, the payment amount
>   can be increased by no more than 20% every 180 days (starting when the
>   profile is created).